Can a compact set $K$ in an open set $U$ be enlarged by $\epsilon$ inside $U$ in a separable complete metric space?
The Problem: Suppose $X, Y$ are separable complete metric spaces, $X$ is compact, $g\in C[X, Y]$ and $g(X)\subseteq U$ for some open set $U\subseteq Y$. Does there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $\underset{x\in X}{\sup}d_Y(g(x), h(x))<\epsilon\implies h(X)\subseteq U$ for all $h\in C[X, Y]$?
My Attempt: I know that there exist open sets $V_0, V_1\subseteq Y$ such that $g(X)\subseteq V_0$, $U^c\subseteq V_1$ and $V_0\cap V_1=\emptyset$. I also know that the distance function $Y\to [0, \infty)$ defined by $y\mapsto\underset{y'\in g(X)}{\inf}d_Y(y, y')$ is continuous. But I didn't get anywhere. Is the original conjecture false? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Take $\varepsilon = d_{Y}(g(X),U^{c}) = \min_{(x,y)\in X\times U^{c}} d_{Y}(g(x),y) > 0$ (this happens because $g(X)$ is compact and $U^{c}$ is closed), hence, if $\sup_{x \in X} d_{Y}(g(x),h(x)) < \varepsilon$, assume by contradiction that there is $x \in X$ such that $h(x) \in U^{c}$, then
$$
d_{Y}(g(x),h(x)) \geq \min_{(x,y)\in X\times U^{c}} d_{Y}(g(x),y) = \varepsilon > \sup_{x \in X} d_{Y}(g(x),h(x))
$$
which is a contradiction, then $h(x) \in U$ for all $x \in X$.
